# Trilinear term in SUSY soft-breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, supersymmetry, symmetry-breaking

In MSSM soft-SUSY breaking, there are such term called 'A-triliear term'.
But, some papers, e.g [Riva-Biggio-Pomarol](http://arxiv.org/abs/1211.4526), do not have trilinear term.

What is the use of introducing trilinear term?